# Iterating the Time for 24 hours for 30 days in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on google analytics  API using the ruby gem. It accepts the parameters and generates the results, I am fetching the data from the seven metrics. It accepts the start time and end time and generates the data according to the Time we pass.

Here is the sample of that

```
Visits.results(pro1, {:start_date => Time.now - 86400, :end_date => Time.now})
```

Which gives me total number of visits for the last 24 hours.

My requirement is little complicated. There are several other metrics also. I need to get the data from the google analytics of previous 30 days. Suppose if I take the dump today it should get me previous 30 days of data. like 28th 27th 26th 25th.... which gets the data of 28th march 2012 00:00:00 to 28th March 2012 59:59:59  , 27th march 2012 00:00:00 to 27th March 2012 59:59:59  and ......I have to trying to achieve this since 2-3 days inruby. I am newbie to ruby. Kindly help me out. TO make the things I need to take data from google analytic s iterating for 24 hours for the past 30 days.

Comment: are you looking for something like 
`(Time.now - 1.days),
(Time.now - 1.months),
(Time.now - 1.years)`

NOTE: its work with rails

Answer (score 1):

If you want results for individual days

```
results = []
30.downto(1) do |n|
  results << Visits.results(pro1, {:start_date => Date.today - n.days, :end_date => Date.today - (n-1).days})
end
```

or if you want them all at once

```
Visits.results(pro1, {:start_date => Date.today - 30.days, :end_date => Date.today})
```

If you want to include today as well then set the end date to `Date.tomorrow`

Comment: From a readability point of view I'd prefer using `n.days.ago`. E.g. `Visits.results(pro1, {:start_date => n.days.ago, :end_date => (n-1).days.ago})`

Comment: n.days.ago includes the time - so `1.day.ago` is yesterday at the current time. Whereas `Date.today-1.day` gives just the date (which is equivalent to yesterday at midnight). If you are using the time portion, this is an important difference

Comment: Good point Shaun, in which case the `Date.today - 1.day` does make sense. Although (and this might just be my personal preference) you could also do `1.day.ago.at_midnight`, or `1.day.ago.to_date`

Comment: I tried all the possibilities which are mentioned her, but nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Visits.results(pro1, {:start_date => Date.today.last_month , :end_date => Date.today})
```